# Solr returns 0 rows when exact matching "#" (hash character)

Tags: solr, lucene

When running a search such as:

```
field_name:#
field_name:"#"
field_name:"\#"
```

where there is a record with the value of exactly "#", Solr returns 0 rows.

The workaround we are having to use is to use a range query on the
 field such as:

```
field_name:[# TO #]
```

and this returns the correct documents.

Use case details:
 We have a field that indexes a text field and calculates a "letter
 group". This keeps only the first significant character from a value
 (number or letter), and if it is a number the simply stores "#" as we
 want all numbered items grouped together.

I'm also aware that we could also fix this by using a specific number
 instead of the hash character, however, I though I'd raise this to see
 if there is a wider issue. I've listed some specific details below.

Field definition:

```
<fieldType name="letterGrouping" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9]).*" group="1"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
<filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z0-9])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([0-9])" replacement="#" replace="all" />
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Server information:

```
 Solr Specification Version: 3.2.0
 Solr Implementation Version: 3.2.0 1129474 - rmuir - 2011-05-30 23:07:15
 Lucene Specification Version: 3.2.0
 Lucene Implementation Version: 3.2.0 1129474 - 2011-05-30 23:08:57
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the fieldtype is applied at both the index and query time.
I tried to check the conversion for # for the fieldtype at query type and it seems to be returning blank.

However, field_name:123 would return back the results, as the 123 should be converted to # and should match the indexed value.

Or just apply the fieldType during index time.

Answer (score 0):

From the solr user group mail list

On 27 October 2011 13:09, Erick Erickson  wrote:

> Take a look at your admin/analysis page and put your tokens in
>   for both  index and query times. What I think you'll see is that the #
>   is being  stripped at query time due to the first
>   PatternReplaceFilterFactory.
>
> You probably want to split your analyzers into an index-time and
>   query-time  pair and do the appropriate replacements to keep # at quer
>   time.

Indeed, the issue was that when querying, the query was also ran through the same analyser. When the input was ran through the first PatternReplaceFilterFactory with the regex:

```
([^a-z0-9])
```

It removed the hash character from the query, therefore deleting the query altogether.

Comment: yup ... can use field_name:123 which when applied through query time should match results. Or just use the field type during indexing only.